# How Can I Avoid -l option with the gcc compiler?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a C application that I am compiling on a Beaglebone Green Wireless development system with the default gcc compiler.  My application has the following headers,

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <malloc.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <resolv.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <openssl/x509.h>
 #include <openssl/ssl.h>
 #include <openssl/err.h>
 #include <assert.h>
 #include <json/json.h>
```

When I compile this application I have to type

```
 gcc edgeclient.c -o edgeclient -l ssl -l crypto -l json
```

Is there a way that I can install the ssl, crypto, and json libraries so I don't have to type all of these -l's?  I am not a lazy typist.  It's just that when I add a new library it is not always clear if I have to add another -l libraryname option.  Would rather clearly understand what is going on than guessing.

Comment: Libraries are linked into the application that you are writing, creating the final application. Each linked library is only required if your app is using the code in the library. If you leave one out and your app fails to link, then it was necessary. If it links and runs, it was never called and can be left out.

Comment: Have you considered writing a Makefile and using `make` to perform your builds?  Then you not only do not need to type all the options, but in the Makefile you have documentation of just what the options should be.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of people who have trouble with the difference between header files and libraries.  If you use a new *library*, you'll need to link to it (with `-l`).  If you add a header, you only need to link to a new library if the header goes with a library you aren't already linking to (and actually use in your code).

Answer (score 0):

These options do not install these libraries but tell the compiler to link your program with these libraries. I suggest you to use a makefile instead where you can write the options once and later on compile by simple typing "make". 
You can always update your makefile if you are trying to use a new library which is not yet added in makefile.
Cmake is another option which provides options for portability.

Comment: I don't think the OP was confused about the meaning of the `-l` options, but using `make` is still good advice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Following statement made me think that the OP has some confusion between linking and installation."Is there a way that I can install the ssl, crypto, and json libraries so I don't have to type all of these -l's?"

Comment: Yes, and that seems to indicate that he understands that the `-l` options indeed do not install the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can install the ssl, crypto, and json libraries so I don't have to type all of these -l's?

You have already installed them on your machine. Otherwise, it wouldn't compile!
They are there to tell the linker to link with those libraries. So, you need them if you are using them in your application. There's no way to avoid them.

> It's just that when I add a new library it is not always clear if I have to add another -l libraryname option

That's easy to find out. If your compilation fails then you are missing one or more libraries! (but compilation may fail for other reasons too).

> Would rather clearly understand what is going on than guessing.

If you have written the application then in all likely you'd know which libraries are needed. Looks like you are compiling code that you don't fully understand.
In that case, the above said "try with out -lblah and add it if it fails" is probably your easier option (and reliable way as well).

Answer (score 0):

> It's just that when I add a new library it is not always clear if I have to add another -l libraryname option. Would rather clearly understand what is going on than guessing.

***First***, you need to understand the difference between adding an `#include` directive for a given *header file* and linking to a given *library*.  A library is a collection of pre-compiled external functions and / or variables that are packaged together such that you can use them in programs without building them from source code with every program.  A header file (generally) provides *declarations* for functions and variables, and perhaps for related data types and macros, such as for the functions and variables provided by a given library.

Any source file containing a call to a given function or an access of a given variable must *declare* that function / variable beforehand.  Making that convenient and minimizing the scope for errors is the reason for header files.  The implementations of all functions and variables used by a program must also be *linked* together to produce an executable.  Therefore, whenever you use a function or variable whose implementation you do not provide yourself, you need to know two things: where (or what) is its declaration, and where is its implementation.  The first is about what header file to include; the latter is about what library needs to be included in the link.

Note that that applies even to the C standard library.  You need to include the appropriate header file for each standard library function you want to use.  Most modern compilers will automatically link most of the standard library to any program, but historically, some required you to link it explicitly, and even today, many compilers require you to explicitly link a library containing the math functions if you want to use any of them.

***Second***, you've posed the wrong question, because which libraries you need to link is not (ordinarily) dependent on which header files you include.  *Both* depend on which variables and functions you use, and both questions are best answered by consulting those functions' and variables' documentation.

Failing that, you may be able to rely on your compiler to tell you about undeclared functions, and you should be able to rely on it to tell you about undeclared variables -- that can help you determine when you need to include additional header files.  You should also be able to rely on your linker to tell you about functions and variables for which no implementation has been provided -- that can help you determine when you need to link additional libraries.

> Is there a way that I can install the ssl, crypto, and json libraries so I don't have to type all of these -l's?

Technically, yes.  You can download their source code, build it along with your existing sources, and link all of the necessary object files together to obtain your final executable.  You may need to perform such source inclusions recursively.  In this way, you can build your program without using any `-l` options, at the cost of requiring a build command that you cannot plausibly expect ever to type out by hand.

And that brings me around to the topic of build systems, such as `make`.  Use one.  Probably `make` itself, directly.  This will save you repetitive typing, ensure that you build consistently with all required options (once you determine what those are), and document your build process and requirements.  For a project as simple as yours appears to be, a Makefile similar to this might well be sufficient:

```
LDLIBS = -lssl -lcrypto -ljson

all: edgeclient
```

Name that `Makefile` and put it in the same directory as `edgeclient.c`.  With that as your working directory, run the `make` command and watch it go.  There are many ways you could embellish on that, and there are some ways you could modify the project that would require embellishments (adding more source files, for example), but that should be enough to get you started, at least with GNU `make` and the GNU toolchain.